# Total Inductance in transformer

Tags: inductor, inductance, coupling, mutual-inductance

[image]

Just a simple question, usually we can determine the sign of the mutual inductance M by seeing the position of the dots (as the current enters through it). But if you see the upper picture, we don't have any dots. How to determine if it's -M or +M from the arrows?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter. As long as you consistently choose to calculate as if the dot is either at the head or the tail of the arrow, the results of your analysis won't change.

That is: Either always put the dot at the head of the arrow or always put the dot at the tail of the arrow.

Comment: Suppose that I put the dot at the head of the arrow, I got \$ M_{lm}, -M_{lr}, M_{ml}, -M_{mr}, M_{rl}, -M_{rm}\$ but the correct answer, everything is positive. Is this a wrong concept of my understanding?

Comment: Sorry, you get \$M_{lm}\$ etc for what? And "the correct answer" to what question?

Comment: Based on the circuit from the first picture

Comment: What is the question about the circuit in the first picture that is supposed to have the answer \$M_{lm}\$, etc.?

Comment: I asked to calculate the total inductance, and this picture has the correct answer as \$ L = L_l+L_m+Lr+2M_{lm}+2M_{mr}+2M_{lr}\$. But in other cases, I also found the equation like this \$ L = L_l+L_m+Lr-2M_{lm}-2M_{mr}-2M_{lr}\$. So, I'm confused how to determine the sign of M, which will affects my calculations later...

Comment: Neither of those answers make any sense. The inductors are connected in parallel, so if there was no mutual inductance (\$M_{xx}=0\$), the answer should be something like \$\frac{L_l L_m + L_l L_r + L_m L_r}{L_l + L_m + L_r}\$, not \$L_l + L_m + L_r\$. Are you sure you're connecting the right answer to the right diagram?

Comment: Yes. I use \$ u_l = L_l{di \over dt}+M_{lm}{di \over dt}+M_{lr}{di \over dt}\$ formula and so on for each leg then sum them up and integrate.

Comment: That is not the right way to calculate the potential across a parallel combination of elements.

Comment: Okay, I will look it up again. Thanks for the useful info.